# Print combination of characters given a sequence

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I was working on the recursive code to print all possible output strings for an input sequence. For simplification I am going to shorten the problem. I have a `String[]` array. I want to print all possible combinations of words from `[0]` to `[N]` considering only one character from a `String` at a time. **Example**: `String[] a = {"abc", "def", "ghi"}` I should be printing `adg, adh, adi, aeg.. etc`
Here is my recursive code:

```
void printLetters(String[] list, int count, String result)
    {
        if(list == null)
            return;
        if(count > list.length-1)
        {
            System.out.println(result);
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<list[count].length(); i++)
        {
            printLetters(list, count++, result + list[count].charAt(i) + "");
        }
    }
```

My code is running into an infinite loop as I am getting a `StackOverflowError`. Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are post-incrementing here:

```
printLetters(list, count++, result + list[count].charAt(i) + "");
```

So the recursive call occurs first, then the increment, which practically means you keep calling the method with the same value of `count`. Use this instead:

```
printLetters(list, count + 1, result + list[count].charAt(i) + "");
```

And are you sure you want to increment `count`? Because when the recursive call returns you will have `count + 1` also in the "parent method", which I don't think is what you need.

Comment: This count + 1 is not good, because it doesn't change the value of count. So it is like calling the same loop, but with a value of 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @Matzi: As I explained in the last sentence, increment is not what he really needs, because the algorithm needs to pass `count + 1` to the next call, not to itself.

Comment: @Tudor: I do need `count+1` in the parent because I will want the next String from the array right??

Comment: @Tudor: It does, I was pointing out that because you were telling me if I would need to increment `count` in the parent.

Comment: @noMAD: I understand now. So in conclusion it should stay `count + 1` and not `++count`.